# How to find all assignment statements where string literal is assigned to variable in Java using antlr or javaparser?

Tags: java, antlr, javaparser

I am trying to find hardcoded string assignment statements in Java. I am trying to use antlr or javaparser but am not getting how to find assignment statements?

Javaparser seems a good way to go. It has support for declarations etc. I am trying to find variable declarations etc but not assignment statements. How can I use that to find assignment statement where a string literal is assigned to a variable.

Comment: please add some code to identify what you try to ask..

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach I used.

- Generate a visual AST of a sample Java file, e.g., one with the hard-coded expression you're looking for. JavaParser can output DOT files (e.g., [blog entry](https://javaparser.org/inspecting-an-ast/)) and that's a great way to spot the nodes in the AST you're interested in.
- I saw from my visualization that the nodes I was interested in were `VariableDeclarator` with an initializer, so I followed the [example](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javaparser/wikis/UsingThisParser.wiki) of using the `VoidVisitorAdapter` and overrode the corresponding `visit` method. A good IDE (IntelliJ) helped me with the rest:

  ```
  public void visit(VariableDeclarator variableDeclarator, Void arg) {
      super.visit(variableDeclarator, arg);
      variableDeclarator.getInitializer().ifPresent(expression -> {
          expression.ifStringLiteralExpr(stringLiteralExpr -> {/* do something */})
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I would try create a listener; listen to the `assignment` statement (line 1196 in Java8.g4) by overwriting the appropriate method, e.g.:

```
    public override void ExitAssignment(Java8Parser.AssignmentContext context);  // C#
```

Check the `context` passed whether
• the `assignmentOperator` is something that could apply to strings (`=`, `+=`)
• and if `expression` resolves to something like `CharacterLiteral` or `StringLiteral`

You get the information via the methods `context.assignmentOperator()` and `context.expression()`.